# find colour property in array of objects

Tags: javascript

Trying to find matching `property` in an `array` of `objects`. I cant get my `find` to pick out the `colour`. Any ideas? I can't get anything to `console.log`

```
const tag = 'lecture';

const eventColour = [
        {
            type: "lecture",
            colour: "red"
        },
        {
            type: "social",
            colour: "blue"
        },
        {
            type: "break",
            colour: "green"
        }
    ]

eventColour.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).find(e => obj[e].type == tag))
```

Comment: Do you want to find the object, or create an array of objects with that type, find just the color, or find the color with that type?

Comment: I just need the colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to get the `colour` of the object with the matching `type`, that would be `find` combined with a property accessor:

```
const obj = eventColour.find(obj => obj.type === tag);
const colour = obj && obj.colour;
```

We need that `&&` guard in case there's no match.

Live Example:

```js
const tag = 'lecture';

const eventColour = [
        {
            type: "lecture",
            colour: "red"
        },
        {
            type: "social",
            colour: "blue"
        },
        {
            type: "break",
            colour: "green"
        }
    ];

const obj = eventColour.find(obj => obj.type === tag);
const colour = obj && obj.colour;
console.log(tag + " => " + colour);

// Example of not finding it:
const tag2 = "not found";
const obj2 = eventColour.find(obj => obj.type === tag2);
const colour2 = obj2 && obj2.colour;
console.log(tag2 + " => " + colour2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const tag = 'lecture';

const eventColour = [{
    type: "lecture",
    colour: "red"
  },
  {
    type: "social",
    colour: "blue"
  },
  {
    type: "break",
    colour: "green"
  }
]

eventColour.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (obj['type'] == tag) {
    console.log(obj['colour'])
  }
});
```

Comment: There's no point in using `map` if you're not mapping. To just loop, use `forEach` (or a loop).

Answer (score 0):

What't the problem with using a good old loop ?

```js
const tag = 'social';
const eventColour = [
        {
            type: "lecture",
            colour: "red"
        },
        {
            type: "social",
            colour: "blue"
        },
        {
            type: "break",
            colour: "green"
        }
    ]

for(var i = 0; i < eventColour.length;i++)
{
 var obj = eventColour[i];
 if (obj['type'] == tag) 
 {
  console.log(obj['colour']);
  break;
 }
}
```